# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable using minidon and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape xml using beautiful soup and minidom but getting errors in python.

Below is my code and error for the same.

**Code:**

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
source = urllib.request.urlopen('somelink.xml').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(soup)
```

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "", line 1,
>   inrunfile('D:/NLTK/Rwire Interface/untitled0.py', wdir='D:/NLTK/Rwire
>   Interface')File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 678, in runfileexecfile(filename, namespace)File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 106, in execfileexec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'),
>   namespace)File "D:/NLTK/Rwire Interface/untitled0.py", line 13, indoc
>   = xml.dom.minidom.parse(soup)File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1958, in
>   parsereturn expatbuilder.parse(file)File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 913, in
>   parseresult = builder.parseFile(file)File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 204, in
>   parseFilebuffer = file.read(16*1024)TypeError: 'NoneType' object is
>   not callable

Comment: So you want to first parse the Source using Beautiful Soup that is soup? and then want to parse that soup again using minidom parse? Both parsers work independently. I want to know what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I basically want to parse XML, and  then extract data inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already parsed see below:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
source = urllib.request.urlopen('somelink.xml').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml') #Soup has parsed data
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(source)  #Doc has parsed data
```

*xml.dom.minidom.parse()* expects xml either in string format or file format. You are providing it with **soup** object which it doesn't accept. Hence your error message.